# Hide separatorColor until UITableView has content

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

How to hide the `separatorStyle` from a `UITableView` until the table has content. In other words, I would like to show the separator lines only when the table has content.

The way I'm currently doing it is adding it in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method which I'm not sure if it is the correct place since it's doing it every time a new row is enter.

Is there a better method to implement this? Any suggestions? is the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` a bad place?

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
// code...
    myTable.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.SingleLine
    myTable.separatorColor = UIColor.myMediumGrayColor()
// code...
}
```

EDIT: Thanks to @**Hems Moradiya**'s answer below, here is what I did that worked. I moved my code to the viewDidLoad method, as follow.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.myTable.tableFooterView = UIView()
    myTable.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.SingleLine
    myTable.separatorColor = UIColor.myMediumGrayColor()
}
```

Comment: Just drag and add a UIView to your tableView's footer, or try what Hems said.

Comment: Hi, I guess you are looking for this. tableVew.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this line in your **ViewDidLoad()**

```
self.Eventlisttable.tableFooterView = UIView()
```

Comment: Otherwise check your array value in this method func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {     if indexpath.row == arr.count {  // hide your separatorline } else {  // show seprator line } }

Comment: I added the `self.Eventlisttable.tableFooterView = UIView()` to viewDidLoad and I got an error. `ViewController has no member of Eventlisttable` What is this suppose to do? Your second approach should work, thanks.

Comment: Eventlisttable is my tableview brother @fs_tigre replace it with your tableview .

Comment: My bad, since your variable was capitalized I just assumed it was a static method or some Swift helper class, again my bad for not looking at the code closely. Even though I'm not exactly sure how adding a tableFooterView makes this work, it worked. Besides adding the code you suggested I also moved my code from the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`to the view `viewDidLoad` and it works.  See my edited question. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @ Himanshu Moradiya - Can some one explain how adding a `UIView` to the footer prevents from showing the `separatorStyle`? From the documentation... https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview/1614976-tablefooterview

Comment: @fs_tigre when you write this line in viewdidload at that time tableviewlast cell have create one black view  so you dont need to write any code for remove black space in tableview after your data cell hope you are clear with my this answer

Comment: @ Himanshu Moradiya - Hmm, if I understand this correctly by default, without adding `tableFooterView`, `UITableView` adds a black-view (black border) to each cell and by adding `tableFooterView = UIView()` we are overriding it with a white empty view, is that correct?

Comment: ya its give a black view to your empty cell contentview. now u got it (y)

Comment: @fs_tigre when ever you use tableview with full less data and tableview hight is big then just write this line and your UI look good .

Comment: One last question, is this the main use for `tableFooterView` or how or where else would you use it for?

Comment: @fs_tigre when ever you need that your last cell content particular data and after that nothing to show at time you can use it otherwise its not necessary to use it

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: @fs_tigre its my pleasure to help you brother.